# Mac OSX OpenGL not getting key events

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, macos-catalina

I'm trying to recompile AGAR (GUI 1.5.0 & 1.6.0) on Mac OSX Catalina.  Latest xcode installed.

On the same system I had until recently had High Sierra and had successfully built AGAR 1.5.0 and was getting key events in all AGAR applications.

I updated to Catalina and updated all brew packages and xcode.

I then tried to compile AGAR 1.6.0 and all went well except I receive no key events in any application.  I can see the keys are output in the terminal the AGAR application was started from.

So I tried recompiling AGAR 1.5.0 (which was previously ok) and that too does not receive key events. If I execute an old AGAR 1.5.0 app that I previously built that works fine but any newly compiled app (AGAR 1.5.0 or AGAR 1.6.0) has no key events.

Since debugging AGAR is beyond the scope of my expertise I am wondering what else might have changed in my High Sierra to Catalina upgrade that I might look at.  I'm suspecting a missing or broken package, but I'm just guessing at this point.

I believe AGAR on Mac OS is built on Cocoa and OpenGL.

I have checked the issues database at github libagar and submitted my issue there but there doesn't appear to much activity.

Comment: [AGAR](https://libagar.org/)?

Comment: AGAR GUI a cross platform windows/forms gui.

Comment: It appears my older version of AGAR was working because I had compiled support for an SDL2 driver so it was probably never using Cocoa!!!  I just recompiled the older version with the SDL2 driver and it is still working!   So I have to assume the code may be at fault!  I will start another question more specific to the code!